# How do I access a FlatList item in my function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `FlatList` component:

```
<FlatList
    data={[
        {key: "Google"},
        {key: "Apple"},
        {key: "Facebook"},
        {key: "Amazon"},
    ]}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

How can I access one of the items in this list? I would like to output to the console the third item in the list using something like `console.log(FlatList.getItem(2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `renderItem`

```
<FlatList
    data={[
        {key: "Google"},
        {key: "Apple"},
        {key: "Facebook"},
        {key: "Amazon"},
    ]}
    renderItem={({item}) => 
    <Button onPress={()=>{
         console.log("Item:", item );
     }}>{item.key}}</Button>
/>
```